# What's the default behaviour of subclass method without using super?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, information-hiding

Is there a possibility to have some default behaviour defined for a method in a subclass, without having to call `super`?

E.g: Suppose we want to set a `boolean` value in the superclass and you want to hide this from the subclass, is there a way to hide the modification of the boolean value? Suppose that we have the following base class `BaseTest`

```
public class BaseTest {
    private boolean mIsInitialized = false;

    public BaseTest() {
    }

    public void initialize() {
        mIsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

and its subclass `Test`:

```
public class Test extends BaseTest {
    public Test() {
    }

    public void initialize() {
    }
}
```

I would like for the call to `Test.initialize()` to set the `mIsInitialized` value to `true` without having to call `super.initialize()`. I would equally like to avoid to define an abstract function in the superclass.
Is this even possible?

Comment: This seems like the exact scenario where you would want to use the super version of a method, as that is how you would set such a "default."  Why are you so opposed to doing so?

Comment: For your current restrictions, no, it is not possible.

Comment: You could declare the method `final` so the base implementation is the only implementation (can't be overridden). That's not what you asked for but might help you implement your solution

Comment: Do you mean that you want `initialize()` in `Test` to behave the same as `initialize()` in `BaseTest`, without explicitly implementing the method in `Test`? That would be a matter of not mentioning the method at all in `Test`.

Comment: Can you change the field to protected and access it in the child class? You could change it directly this way.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Because then you expect that your user will need to know that he has to call super. In my case, I already know that I want some default behavior, so I don't want to bother the user of the library to call super.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@rgettman et al. are calling for using the [Template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  Therein you make explicit the fact that subclasses may "hook in" to the superclass's action through specific overridable methods that are not `initialize`, which seems to go against the spirit of your question.

You can also use an aspect-oriented framework like AspectJ to have all kinds of invisible behaviors attached to method calls.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Template pattern, which basically was what I wanted to avoid with the abstract functions (I just learned the thing has a name :))

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some Java language construct that would let me do what I wanted to do without having to resort to aspect-oriented programming or code injection. Your answer is the closest to what I wanted to do. I'll accept if no one shows up with a Java-construct.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do this, but not by overriding `initialize`.  In the `BaseTest` class, mark `initialize` as `final` so it cannot be overridden.  In `initialize`, call another method to do any subclass initialization.

```
public final void initialize() {
    mIsInitialized = true;
    initializeFurther();
}
```

You said no `abstract` methods.  But, `initializeFurther` can just be made empty.

```
protected void initializeFurther() {}
```

Then, the subclass `Test` just needs to override `initializeFurther`.

```
public class Test extends BaseTest {
    @Override
    protected void initializeFurther() {
       // Initialize Test here.
    }
}
```

The base class's `initialize` method is guaranteed to set `mIsInitialized` to `true`, and `Test` can implement `initializeFurther` however it wants, without calling `super.initialize()`.  `Test` can't stop the superclass `BaseTest` from doing its initialization.

When `initialize` is called on any `BaseTest` instance, the `initialize` logic will always run.

Comment: I don't quite get this answer. The question says the developer wants to change the value of `mIsInitialized` to true declared in the parent class without invoking the initialize method. But this solution makes the field final and already initialized to true. So, what would be the point? If that is case, we could simply set the field to true from the beginning. Or set the field to protected and change it in the child class. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I think my answer hits all the requirements.  The subclass method doesn't call `super.initialize()`.  The `initialize` method in `BaseTest` is `final` to prevent `Test` from overriding `initialize` and doing something like not calling `super.initialize()`.  This prevents an overriding method from stopping the base class from initializing.  At the same time, the hook method `initializeFurther` is provided so that an outside call to `initialize` will still get the subclasses initialized, and it also guarantees that `BaseTest`' `initialize` method will run as intended.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I read this question as how to prevent the subclass `Test` from preventing the superclass `BaseTest`'s initialization of `mIsInitialized` to `true`.  Without this, it would be possible for `Test` to override `initialize` and not call `super.initialize`, thus bypassing `BaseTest`'s initialization.  The "default behaviour" of `initialize` is preserved.

Comment: @rgettman The user of the library will mainly work on the inherited classes. Nevertheless, the underlying framework will need to access the members of the superclasses. E.g.: in this case the framework might throw an error if the user forgot to call Test.initialize().

Answer (score 0):

If you prevent Test from overriding BaseTest's initialize(), you can call BaseTest's initialize() directly. Here's some test code:

```
public class BaseTest {
   private boolean mIsInitialized = false;

   public BaseTest() {
   }

   public void initialize() {
    mIsInitialized = true;
    System.out.println(mIsInitialized);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
    Test test = new Test();
    test.initialize();

   }

}


class Test extends BaseTest {
   public Test() {
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the point is avoiding the call to `initialize` in the super class. This is doing exactly that. Isn't it?

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but he still said he wants to call the method at some point: "I would like for the call to Test.initialize()..." This could help if he didn't want to call it twice.